# Check if infinite series divisible individually by a number or not?

Tags: python-3.x

We are given first three numbers of a infinite series and the next elements of series would be decided by following formula:

`Tn= Tn-1 + Tn-2 + Tn-3`

If we are given the first three numbers as 1, 1, 1, then the series would look like this:

```
1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, . . . .
```

Now I wanted to ask the logic on how to check if all the elements of the series are indivisible by a number individually. For example, we know that the above series is not divisible by 27.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a math problem. It may be a better fith for https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: You want to find *one* number that divides *all* elements?

Comment: I want to find the list of numbers which don't divide any element of the series. Like 27 never divides any element of the list.

Comment: Agreed. Python is an imperative and procedural language, blindly attempting to process each element of an infinite series would take an infinite amount of time. You would need to find a mathematical/logical way to simplify the problem to deduce your answer without computing an infinite list.

Comment: Okay sure timgeb and @TrevorIanPeacock , I too tried to do it mathematically by finding the general element but that too needs to be computed, so this all becomes the same thing, I thought if anyone encountered the same problem and have any answers on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our problem is concerned with the modulus of a third order linear recurrence, or [Tribonacci numbers](http://oeis.org/A000213).

We cant check the entire infinite series, but by taking a modulus of each term, if a term in the series is divisible, we will get modulo 0.

```
Sequence: 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 9, 17, 31, 57, 105
Modulo 7: 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 2,  3,  3,  1,   0
```

We don't care about the terms of the sequence, only their modulus. Further as the modulus operator is distributive ([almost](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147140/what-are-the-properties-of-the-modulus)), we can modify the sequence to `Tn= ( Tn-1 + Tn-2 + Tn-3 ) mod X`, where `X` is the divisor we are testing.

We now have an infinite sequence of a finite set of numbers. Each term must be between `0` and `X-1` (inclusive), meaning there is at most `X^3` possibilities for each triple. If `X` is not divisible into any term, the sequence must eventually repeat, returning to `1, 1, 1`

Starting with `T0 = 1, T1 = 1, T2 = 1`, we find `T117 mod 27 = 1, T118 mod 27 = 1, T119 mod 27 = 1`

Given all this we can write a program that will terminate.

```
def isDivisible(x):
    # We'll pre-compute the 3rd term of the sequence
    l = [1,1,3]
    # We will compute the modulus of the sequence
    #     until we generate a 0,
    #     or we repeat to 1,1,1
    while (l[2] > 0 and l[0]*l[1]*l[2]!=1):
        l = [l[1], l[2], sum(l) % x]
    #if we generated a 0, x is divisible
    return l[2]==0

print(isDivisible(7))
print(isDivisible(27))
```

See also [Project Euler solution](https://blog.dreamshire.com/project-euler-225-solution/)